# Ansible and JMESPath, escape forward slash in a json_query

Tags: ansible, jmespath

There is a simple JSON file, `sample.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "test": {
    "domain": [
      {
        "name": "cluster1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With Ansible, I want to query over the `test` key, which works with the following Ansible playbook.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    tmpdata: "{{ lookup('file','sample.json') | from_json }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ tmpdata | json_query('test') }}"
```

The play

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "domain": [
            {
                "name": "cluster1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, when they key in the JSON file is changed, from `test` to `test/something`, and the ansible json_query from `test` to `test/something` as well, Ansible/JMESPath produces an error.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "JMESPathError in json_query filter plugin:\nBad jmespath expression: Unknown token /:\ntest/something\n    ^"}
```

I've looked into the [JMESpath documentation](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#grammar), but it does not make sense to me.

How can I ensure JMESpath works with forward slashes in the Ansible query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMESPath defines `identifier` as `unquoted-string / quoted-string`.

`unquoted-string` is `A-Za-z_`. Anything else should be quoted.

In your case:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ tmpdata | json_query('\"test/something\"') }}"
```

Here we escape `\"` because we are inside YAML double quotes `msg: "..."`.